# HTML Div resizing that has elements in it

Tags: html

I know how to resize a div, but this one that I'm working with has a lot of elements inside it, like buttons, etc.  How could I resize those all in one shot? I really don't want to manually resize each one.

Comment: in general, if you want them to resize together, use relative sizing with %, but you should show some markup and existing css for specific recommendations

Comment: so you're saying relative sizing with the container div?

Comment: yes, jsfiddle provided in below answer

Comment: okay, thanks.  i think this will help

Answer (score 1):

Use % and it will resize relative to the size of the containing element. In this fiddle, the css for the button is the same, but is relative to the size of the containing element. I've used percentages for the padding as that's what I'm using for the size of the button here, but you can use it on width/height as well if you wish:

[relative sizing (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ADdUK/1/)

One thing to note - because the font size isn't being set relatively here, the button size isn't scaling the same way, but you can use percentages for that as well.